# Nlog to log errors across all ASP.NET Core and Class Libraries (Dependency Injection)

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, nlog

In my recent applications I was using Nlog to log errors and debugging info across all my projects. I developed a class library that wraps Nlog and used static methods to call Nlog functions.
The problem is that I didn't use DI, So I can add refrence to the Wrapper library from My ASP.net applications and class libraries.

Now, I am in process of developing ASP.NET Core APPs where I can use the build DI services.

```
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
  {
       //add NLog to ASP.NET Core
          loggerFactory.AddNLog();

      env.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config");
  }
```

Then, I can get the ILogger in API Contollers to log my messages. However, this logger will be available only in the Site, what about logging any errors or info happening in other class libraries such as the repository layer. How would that be implemented to be shared across all my class libraries

Comment: Did you even try it? You can inject `ILogger<T>` in every class that resolved via DI. You should even get the logs other frameworks/libraries does (like ASP.NET Core, EntityFramework etc.). The ILogger implementation is just a proxy that reidrecty the logged messages to the registered log providers

Comment: I didn't try it yet. But, I was suspicious about that. That's why I was asking. I will try to implement it.

Comment: Hi, Did that work for you?